# How to print out a full q/a entry? Or forward it outside the stackexchange site?

Tags: support

using either firefox or ie on a windows xp workstation, i've tried to print out the full entries for several questions.  however, any entry that was longer than could be accommodated by one side of a sheet of paper was truncated, and if i duplexed the job, the first line(s?) of the entry were missing from the top of the second page.

i actually reported such a bug several months ago -- directly to the management, before i had an account and could actually post questions -- and thought it had been fixed.  but it seems to have resurfaced.

as keeper of the bugs list for the ams-latex macro/style collection, full documentation of bug reports is important to me. having a "local" copy is essential, either paper or electronic, although a link will be checked later during the implementation. i will probably end up cutting and pasting the entire content of the relevant questions, but that surely isn't the best or easiest approach. is there a better way that i'm just overlooking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recommend **using StackPrinter for printing duties**:

http://stackprinter.appspot.com/

This was built using our API at

http://stackapps.com

and it was a contest winner too!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/stack-exchange-api-contest-winners/

Comment: splendid!  thanks!

Comment: Works great, but could we have some link to it on the site? Or at least mention it in the FAQs?

Answer (score 9):

You could also use [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda)'s [TeXPrinter](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/texprinter), which produces PDF or LaTeX output. He wrote a [blog entry](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/printing-tex-sx-threads/) about it.

Comment: very nice indeed, but is it running somewhere on the net?  (i'm prohibited from installing *any* software on the system from which i usually read tex.sx.  am also strongly discouraged from downloading photos or music either.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'm afraid it runs locally only. But it doesn't require installation, you just need to have the proper Java runtime environment (?) installed.

Comment: It is customary not to provide a solution via external links because they may disappear. Can you explain in detail how to use this solution to print a question and answers with Paulo Cereda's tool? An example of use would be welcome.