# using StackPrinter, question id not found

Tags: support

i've been happily using StackPrinter ever since i learned about it (answer to my own
[question 825](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-to-print-out-a-full-q-a-entry-or-forward-it-outside-the-stackexchange-site) in this forum), but today it is
telling me the question/answer i want to print out is "not found!"

the group is TeX-LaTeX and the question id is 3473.  i can access this question by
typing in the url directly, so i know i've got the number right.  i've checked in
the faq of the group where stackprinter is covered (by following links in the answer
to the aforementioned question), but can't find where to submit a
query or bug report.  i've followed links as far as github, which appears to be the
host on which the tool is maintained, but to raise an issue there, one has to log in;
i have no other reason to do that just now, so i'd rather not.

where, then, is the correct place to post this report?

Comment: Works for me. Maybe there was a temporary technical problem?

Comment: @Caramdir, it's behaving now (i did keep trying for a couple of hours before posting).  thanks for adding the link -- i'm still learning how to cope with all the little formatting niceties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackPrinter has suffered some connectivity issues from Google App Engine to the StackExchange API; the problem is now solved.

For question, feedback, issues and suggestion feel free to leave a comment on the official [StackPrinter post](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite).