# How to print question and answer

Tags: support

I asked a question and got several comments and answers which I wanted to print as hard copy (the paperless office is an enduring con). My browser is Firefox and when I pushed the Print button it prints as a single page with the majority of the Q&A off the bottom of the page. I estimate that at least 3 pages should have been printed.

What is the way to print a full Q&A?

Comment: There was a tool by Paulo Cereda designed for this, but I can't remember its name, right now

Comment: TexPrinter, that's the name, but the link on Paulo's profile site is dead ...

Comment: Please see related question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-to-print-out-a-full-q-a-entry-or-forward-it-outside-the-stackexchange-site Duplicate?

Comment: Unfortunately the new site "design" broke the ability to print questions and answers with firefox. I'm collecting interesting posts by printing them as pdf and to do this I currently use the following stupid workaround: I feed all the post I want to print to an RSS news feed reader (I use `vienna.app` for mac) and print (to pdf in my case) from there.

Comment: related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317013/css-bug-with-printing-site-pages-now-with-100-more-suggested-fix-included