# Adding the Stack Printer app button to each post

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to request a button be placed with each post that allows for the printing of questions and their answers via [the Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com). Can this be done?

Comment: 1. I think this type of change (is unlikely to happen and) should be asked in the main meta site (https://meta.stackexchange.com). 2. You can see your starred questions in your user profile, under the “Favorites” tab.

Comment: To print Q&As, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2165/101651

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print out a full q/a entry? Or forward it outside the stackexchange site?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-to-print-out-a-full-q-a-entry-or-forward-it-outside-the-stackexchange-site)

Comment: requested a button to be added which runs stackprinter--rather than moving to an external website

Comment: starred questions can be viewed but should be able to filter them by there tags==for example starred questions for `tables` or `circiuitikz`

Comment: For searching the starred posts in your favorites with some tags type: `infavorites=mine [tables]` or `infavorites=mine [circuitikz]`. The other feature reaquest should be ask on the main SE Meta site.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not likely to be implemented on a network-wide basis. In the interim, [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/q/179/27724) can form part of a [Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/77298.html) that you can install which will add a button with every question.